# Using XML::Twig, how to check that two nodes have exactly the same children and attributes?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, perl-module, xml-twig

Here is a short XML file with 2 nodes having the same children (but with 2 different values).

5000 for the node MIAMI

7777 for the node WASHINGTON

```
<country id="USA">
<city id="MIAMI" method="modify">
    <attributes>
        <number_people>5000</number_people>
        <average_income>40</average_income>
    </attributes>
</city>

<city id="WASHINGTON" method="modify">
    <attributes>
        <number_people>7777</number_people>
        <average_income>40</average_income>

    </attributes>
 </city>
</country>
```

**Using Perl::Twig, I want to check if the nodes MIAMI and WASHINGTON are IDENTICAL (having the same children and the same values).**

Here is what I did which is not working
($M->children eq $W->children) is found to be TRUE. 
It should be false since "number_people" value is different.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $t= XML::Twig->new;
my $v= XML::Twig::Elt->new;

$t-> parsefile ('file.xml');
my $M=$t->first_elt('city');            # retrieve node MIAMI 
my $W=$M->next_sibling('city');    # retrieve node WASHINGTON


if ($M->children eq $W->children) {print "the two nodes are exactly IDENTICAL"; }
```

Comment: Would a third city `LOS ANGELES` with 7777 people be identical to `WASHINGTON`? Their names are different, so the data structures probably are, too. I think what needs to be compared are the children of the actual city data structure.

Comment: yes you are right. That is why I tried to use $M->children. But it does not seem to contain the attribute values

Comment: It's amusing to see elements wrapped in an 'attributes' node

Comment: to start with `$t->first_elt('MIAMI')` will NOT retrieve the node MIAMI, you need to use `$t->first_elt('city')`, then `$M->children` returns either the list of children, or in scalar context, ie when you test it, the number of children. Why would it contain the text value of a sub element?

Comment: @mirod right, that was a type mistake (I use dummy name as I can't post original data). I will correct the question code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's about module [Data::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Data-Compare-1.22/lib/Data/Compare.pm), it help to compare two perl data structures recursively.

I check documentation for module XML::Twig you can get structure of any TWIG object using method `simplify`. So `$M->children->simplify`

Comment: if possible, I would prefer to use a built-in method from Perl::Twig. If I had to dump the two node, do you think I must use:  $M->simplify, $W->simplify, then use Data::Compare to compare $M and $W ?

Comment: I suggest you try it. But since an object is nothing more than a blessed data structure, maybe it works with just `$M->children` versus `$W->children`.

Comment: @fxzuz You helped a lot to find a solution                      `       my $ATR=$Y1->simplify();
 my $ATRIB=$Y2->simplify();
 my $z1=Dumper ($ATR);
 my $z2=Dumper ($ATRIB);                                   if ($z1 eq $z2)    
  {print "\n NODES_attributes EQUALS";}`

Comment: note that I do not know if there was a solution using purely Twig (here we use Data::Dumper). We do not need to use the children method (simplify is recursive)